# Getting data back from Flask server after an Ajax GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I am experimenting with Flask and Ajax. On the server side I have a very simple web application that should double and return a number passed to it, which I wrote cribbing from the example on the Flask web site. Here is the Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

# Initialize the application

app = Flask(__name__)

# Route that receives and processes the Ajax request
@app.route('/')
def index():
    print 'In index()'
    data = request.args.get('data', 0, type=int) 
    print 'Received Ajax post - Data: ', data
    return jsonify(dict(results=str(data*2)))

# Main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
            host = '0.0.0.0',
            port = int('8080'),
            debug = True # TODO: Disable debug mode after testing is complete
            )
```

On the client side, the relevant fragment is:

```
$('#dataSubmitBtn').button().click(submitAdditionalData);

function submitAdditionalData() {
    var j = $.getJSON(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
        {data: 15}, // Payload
        function(returnedData) { // Success function
            console.log('Data returned from server: ', returnedData.results);
        }
    ).done(function() {
        console.log('Successful execution');
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log('Error');
    }).always(function() {
        console.log('Complete');
    });
    return false;
}
```

When I run this Python class and open my web page, the functions for the fail and always cases are executed, but the ones for success are never executed. However, if I type

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/?data=30
```

in my browser bar, I get

```
{

    "results": "60"

}
```

which is what I believe I should expected. Is the problem in the Javascript code? In the Python code? Maybe both?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: The HTML page and the Python app are both on the same server, but yes, the first is served by Apache on port 80 and the second is served by the Flask development server on port 8080. So that's the problem?

Comment: Different ports are different origins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SLaks mentioned, you were trying to fetch data from another domain, which is not allowed under [Same Origin Policy (SOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), but allowed by using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

To use JSONP, you need to make some change on the server side. Here is an example for [JSONP in Flask](https://gist.github.com/farazdagi/1089923). And then, on the client side, a `callback`(as defined by the server side) parameter is required. If you are using `jQuery.getJSON`, check the [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jsonp) for more details.

Comment: Ok, I can solve this by stopping using the development server and deploying Flask under Apache as I was planning to do.